# Join three tables together to get one value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, relationship, sql-insert

I'm new to Postgresql and I have three tables:

```
=# SELECT * FROM employee_names;
 employee_id | employee_name
-------------+---------------
           1 | Johannes
           2 | Günter
           3 | Elsabeth

=# SELECT * FROM projects;
 employee_id | last_project
-------------+--------------
           1 | 5
           2 | 15
           3 | 8

=# SELECT * FROM last_project_systems_used;
 employee_id | last_project | systems_used
-------------+--------------+--------------
           1 |            5 |           11
           1 |            5 |           18
           2 |           15 |            4
           3 |            8 |           10
           3 |            8 |            7
           3 |            8 |            2
```

- `employee_id` in `employee_names` is pri key and serial.
- `employee_name` is unique. Yes I know in typical use cases a name should NOT be given unique treatment as people can easily have identical names but in my example it's unique.
- `employee_id` in `projects` is pri key.
- `last_project` is not null integer and the number can be repeated in both tables (the project number of the last project they worked on)
- `systems_used` is unique (the system number they worked on, will always be unique values)

To summarize:

- Johannes has an employee_id of 1, his last project was #5, and he used both systems 11 and 18 in his project.
- Günter has an employee_id of 2, his last project was #15, and he used both system 4 in his project.
- Elsabeth has an employee_id of 3, her last project was #8, and she used systems 10, 7 and 2 in her project.

I need to run an insert query somewhat like the following:

```sql
    INSERT INTO last_project_systems_used 
    VALUES ((SELECT employee_id FROM employee_names 
    WHERE employee_name = 'Günter'), 
    (SELECT last_project FROM projects 
    WHERE (SELECT employee_id FROM employee_name 
    WHERE employee_name = 'Günter')), 9);
```

This would check what the employee_id is for Günter (2), find what his last project number was (15) and add system number 9 into the table.

That update would look like:

```
 employee_id | last_project | systems_used
-------------+--------------+--------------
           1 |            5 |           11
           1 |            5 |           18
           2 |           15 |            4
           3 |            8 |           10
           3 |            8 |            7
           3 |            8 |            2
           2 |           15 |            9
```

Though I am having trouble with the part where I get the last project number from the employee with the name Günter, since only his id is listed in the projects table and not his name.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should not store the `last_project` in two different tables. Keep it in the `projects` table. If you need a table of the format of your current `last_project_systems_used`, use a `JOIN` for that query.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, this works much more elegantly

Answer (score 2):

Use `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO last_project_systems_used (employee_id, last_project, systems_used)
    SELECT en.employee_id, p.last_project, 9
    FROM projects p JOIN
         employee_names en
         ON p.employee_id = en.employee_id
    WHERE en.employee_name = 'Günter';
```

Comment: Thanks but I get `ERROR:  column reference "employee_id" is ambiguous` `LINE 2: SELECT employee_id, last_project, 9` with an arrow pointing to employee_id.

Comment: You can use `USING` instead of `ON` as the join condition, which leads to only one `employee_id` column in the result.

Comment: @Bergi `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "p"` `LINE 5: USING p.employee_id = en.employee_id`

Comment: @leetbacoon See [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-select.html) for the correct syntax: `FROM projects JON employee_names USING (employee_id)`. Alternatively you could use a `NATURAL JOIN` here.

Comment: @leetbacoon . . . I should have originally qualified all the column references and have fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff, this does work as well. What is your opinion on the query I wrote below? Visually it is easier for me to understand. Do they both function identically?

Comment: @leetbacoon . . . (1) Your query doesn't work.  (2)  I think `insert . . . select` is much simper to understand than `insert . . . values` with multiple subqueries.  That might be a matter of opinion of course.

Comment: @GordonLinoff When I learnt SQL I was only covered on `INSERT . . . VALUES`, never on `INSERT . . . SELECT` hence why I was unaware

Comment: @leetbacoon . . . That is a shame.  `INSERT . . . SELECT` is more general.  As a rule, `INSERT . . . VALUES` is not really needed -- well, except in some cases where you want to specify default values.

Comment: Okay I see, thank you for noting that. I'll have some reworking to do

Answer (score 0):

With enough trial and error I found this this appears to do the trick, if there are better solutions to this or if my SQL sounds bad please let me know.

```
INSERT INTO last_project_systems_used VALUES
((SELECT employee_id FROM employee_names
WHERE employee_name = 'Günter'),
(SELECT last_project FROM projects
WHERE employee_id = (SELECT employee_id FROM employee_names
WHERE employee_name = 'Günter')), 9);
```

Comment: Yes, this sounds bad, because of the duplication of `SELECT employee_id FROM employee_names
WHERE employee_name = 'Günter'`. To avoid that without using a JOIN, you can use a nested query: `INSERT INTO last_project_systems_used SELECT (emloyee_id, (…), 9) FROM employee_names 
WHERE employee_name = 'Günter')` where the `…` part is `(SELECT last_project FROM projects
WHERE projects.employee_id = employee_names.employee_id)`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. If `employee_name` were specified as UNIQUE would that deem my solution functionally sound?

Comment: Functionally sound I guess yes, but code duplication is still bad.

Comment: Not to argue, but how come duplicated code is bad? Is it slower? More prone to typos? Generally bad practice?

Comment: Yes, it's error-prone and less maintainable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code

Comment: @Bergi Just tried out your code, I like it! I always thought `INSERT INTO` queries needed `VALUES` specified. Anyway, does the `last_project_systems_used` table need any special properties when it's created or is something like this okay: https://pastebin.com/raw/NyHXiGB1

Comment: Seems fine. By avoiding the `last_project` column, it also makes the `INSERT` much simpler :-)